# jquery element is not a function

Tags: jquery

Hi I have followed the example to get this carousel working [carousel link](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

It works fine in Internet Explorer however when I run it in firefox I get the error TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

I keep looking and can't see any differences in my code to the example and can't understand how it would work in IE and not firefox

```
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.flow.1.2.auto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel">
    <div><img src="img/carousel/1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/carousel/2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/carousel/coutout2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/carousel/cutout.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="img/carousel/cutout1.jpg" /></div>
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".modalbox").fancybox();

                $('.carousel').slick({
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 450,
                    adaptiveHeight: true
                    });

                $("#Logo").show();


    $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });

                //send email
    $("#send").on("click", function(){
        var emailval  = $("#email").val();
        var msgval    = $("#message").val();
        var msglen    = msgval.length;
        var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

                    //
        if(mailvalid == false) {
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(mailvalid == true){
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

        if(msglen < 4) {
            $("#msg").addClass("error");
        }
        else if(msglen >= 4){
            $("#msg").removeClass("error");
        }
        //

                     mailvalid == true

    if(mailvalid == true     && msglen >= 4) {
            $("#send").replaceWith("<em>sending...</em>");

            $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                url: 'contact_form/contact.php',
                data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == "true") {
                        $("#contact").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                            $(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
                            setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });


            //validate email
            function validateEmail(email) { 
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return reg.test(email);
}
        });
```

Comment: I don't think that it's the problem since it's working in IE but I don't see jQuery included. Do you see any other error or 404 error in the developer console ?

Comment: have you got Jquery included??? i think you must if its working in IE

Comment: That's the kind of error you'd get when jQuery is not included.  In that case, it should not be working in IE either, although IE is notorious for caching everything until the end of time.

Comment: Are your testing this locally by opening the file in your browser, or running it from a web server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have JQuery included. It doesn't recognize your selector. Try adding version 1.11 for instance. Add this script before your other two:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**

Assuming you have jQuery already loaded, I think it has something to do with the referencing. You don't have `http:` prefixing the source of the script, which might be something IE is correcting automatically. Change your scripts to have `http` in them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i understand your answer and it is correct in the content but he said its working in IE which means he must be referencing jQuery

Comment: @JoshStevens That's true, I haven't noticed it. Noticed something else though... editing.

Comment: yes if your web page is HTTP then you should link to HTTP link but if its a HTTPS web page you should source to HTTPS link as cross HTTPS/HTTP gets blocked on chrome

Comment: There's nothing wrong with leaving off the scheme, unless he's trying to use the code from his local machine.  When you leave off the scheme, the browser will automatically use the correct protocol.

Comment: @Sparky That's what I'm betting on.

Comment: have tried the https and http no difference.  I have copied the sample code into a clean page and it works perfectly fine in both browsers.  I have references  to other Jquery plugins one of these must be knocking it out.  Just don't understand why one browser works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @user2247671 Yeah, indeed very weird. Maybe we need to see some more code.

Comment: @user2247671 I created this plunker from your code (except the local fancybox stuff) and it seems to work on FF: http://plnkr.co/edit/yobKOzodxLuuTivXulHU?p=preview

Comment: yes that runs both browsers I think my issue lies more in the fancy box!!

Answer (score 0):

If your web page is HTTP then you should link to HTTP link but if its a HTTPS web page you should link to HTTPS link as cross HTTPS/HTTP gets blocked on chrome and other browsers for security reasons. This probably the the case, correct it as you must either:

HTTP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTTPS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you can also use something called fiddler which catches everything from your web page 404s, service calls etc http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

you can also look in your console log and it will tell you the issue.